# Filling missing dates on a DataFrame across different groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have the following DataFrame in Pandas

| date | customer | attended |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | John | True |
| 2022-01-02 | John | True |
| 2022-01-04 | John | True |
| 2022-01-05 | Mark | True |

what transformations could I do to fill in the missing gaps within the dates on a given frequency (daily in this case, but it can by any other) so it ends up like this:

| date | customer | attended |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | John | True |
| 2022-01-01 | Mark | False |
| 2022-01-02 | John | True |
| 2022-01-02 | Mark | False |
| 2022-01-03 | John | False |
| 2022-01-03 | Mark | False |
| 2022-01-04 | John | True |
| 2022-01-04 | Mark | False |
| 2022-01-05 | John | False |
| 2022-01-05 | Mark | True |

This can be done on an individual level by filtering on just one **customer** and doing an outer join with another DataFrame that has all the dates, and it will fill the empty ones with NaNs, but I can't do that with all the different people at **customer** which is what I need to do. I'd appreciate an approach that's as computationally efficient as possible and doesn't involve a lot of convoluted iterations over the dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try it with `pivot` + `date_range` + `reindex` + `stack`:

```
tmp = df.pivot('date','customer','attended')
tmp.index = pd.to_datetime(tmp.index)
out = tmp.reindex(pd.date_range(tmp.index[0], tmp.index[-1])).fillna(False).stack().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'attended'})
```

Output:

```
     level_0 customer  attended
0 2022-01-01     John      True
1 2022-01-01     Mark     False
2 2022-01-02     John      True
3 2022-01-02     Mark     False
4 2022-01-03     John     False
5 2022-01-03     Mark     False
6 2022-01-04     John      True
7 2022-01-04     Mark     False
8 2022-01-05     John     False
9 2022-01-05     Mark      True
```

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way (`df` your dataframe):

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)  # Just in case

customers = df.customer.unique()
df_fill = pd.DataFrame(
    (
        [day, customer]
        for day in pd.date_range(df.date.min(), df.date.max(), freq="D")
        for customer in customers
    ),
    columns=["date", "customer"]
)
df = df_fill.merge(df, on=["date", "customer"], how="left")
df.attended = df.attended.fillna(False)
```

Output:

```
        date customer  attended
0 2022-01-01     John      True
1 2022-01-01     Mark     False
2 2022-01-02     John      True
3 2022-01-02     Mark     False
4 2022-01-03     John     False
5 2022-01-03     Mark     False
6 2022-01-04     John      True
7 2022-01-04     Mark     False
8 2022-01-05     John     False
9 2022-01-05     Mark      True
```

Comment: It's a nice workaround but on a big dataset with a big amount of different customer names/ids and as the dates grow longer the nested for loop (O(n^2)) takes an infinite amount of time.

Comment: @lorenzoDM Good point.

Answer (score 0):

One option is with the [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), to expose the explicitly missing rows:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

# generate new dates
new_dates = {"date": pd.date_range(df.date.min(), df.date.max(), freq="D")}

df.complete(new_dates, 'customer', sort = True).fillna({'attended':False})

        date customer  attended
0 2022-01-01     John      True
1 2022-01-01     Mark     False
2 2022-01-02     John      True
3 2022-01-02     Mark     False
4 2022-01-03     John     False
5 2022-01-03     Mark     False
6 2022-01-04     John      True
7 2022-01-04     Mark     False
8 2022-01-05     John     False
9 2022-01-05     Mark      True
```